# 2005 Civic Lower Control Arm replacement or Bushing?

Tags: honda, civic, bushing

My Front Passenger side compliance bushing is bad. I can get the bushing for $27, or I can get the entire control arm (including bushing) for $41.

Wouldn't it be worth it just to change out the entire arm (since i have to remove the arm to get to the bushing anyways)?

It just seems like its worth it (to me, at least) to pay the extra $14 so I wouldn't need to remove the bad bushing and press in the new one.

I've never changed out a compliance bushing (or control arm), so is there anything I should watch out for?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Most control arm bushings require some type of mechanical or hydraulic press to install then in to the control arm. If you don't have access to a press you will have to pay someone to do it. This requires you to remove the arm and bring it somewhere.  The cost in labor is likely going raise the cost to higher than the price of the arm with the bushing installed.